# Select records from fact table with multiple conditionals on the same dimension table

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

Let's say I have a survey data schema, my fact table represents each person responding this survey, one of the dimension tables has all the answers to the survey, what's the most efficient way to get all the records from the fact table that match multiple conditionals on the answers table?

FACT TABLE (records):

```
| id | name | date | gender |
```

DIMENSION TABLE (answers):

```
| record_id | question_id | value |
```

I could do a new left join for every question, but this seems very inneficient if I want to find a record that answered multiple questions

```
SELECT * FROM records r 
    left join answers a on r.id = a.record_id 
    left join answers a2 on r.id = a2.record_id 
    where (a.question_id = 1 and a.value = 2) 
    and (a2.question_id = 3 and a2.value = 1);
```

Any alternative to this?

Comment: don't you have a "correct answer" table?

Comment: not in this case, it's a survey not a test so all answers are correct

Comment: what exactly do you want to get as output? i dont understand the text about what your goal is

Comment: the goal is to get all the records for people who gave specific answers to specific questions. It's for a data research tool, so each user might have completely different questions. as an example in text: "Select all users who answered ''chocolate" as they favorite food and answered "red" as their favorite color and answered "US" as their country "

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you need:

```
   SELECT 
       *
     FROM records r 
LEFT JOIN answers a ON r.id            = a.record_id
                   AND a.question_id   = 1 
                   AND a.value         = 2 
LEFT JOIN answers a2 ON r.id           = a2.record_id 
                    AND a2.question_id = 3 
                    AND a2.value       = 1;
```

Comment: this is what I'm trying to avoid using, the query might have a very large number of conditions for the dimensional table, so if for each one of them I have to do a new left join it won't be efficient at all

Comment: @StackOverMySoul okay, I just didn't understand what you need. Could you show the expected table. What do you want to receive after completing the request? At least what it looks like in your mind.

Answer (score 0):

After some more digging it looks like the most scalable and dynamic way is using `EXISTS`

```
SELECT * FROM records r  WHERE 
  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM answers WHERE record_id = r.id AND question_id = 1 AND value = 1) AND
  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM answers WHERE record_id = r.id AND question_id = 3 AND value = 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would hardcode the list of questions/values you want and use join:

```
with
 question_filter as (
    select 1 as question_id, 2 as value
    union select 3, 1
)
select *
from records r
join answers a
on r.id=a.record_id
join question_filter
using (question_id,value)
;
```